# CSV parsed into three dimensional HashMap in Java

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I'm attempting to parse a CSV file into a HashMap. The CSV file contains name, email and age.

I've attempted it below but haven't had any luck progressing with it - beginner to Java

```
public class Extract {

    public HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> readFile(String filename)   {

        HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> people = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            String line;

            while(in.hasNext()) {
                line = in.nextLine();
                String[] keyValue = line.split(",");
                people.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[2], keyValue[3]);
            }
            in.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return people;
    }
}


import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Extract e = new Extract();

        String peopleFile = ("relationships.csv");
        HashMap<String, String> person1 = e.readFile(peopleFile);
        person1.get("Bob");
    }
   }
```

Comment: *I've attempted it below but haven't had any luck progressing with it*.. Whats the objective? What's not working?

Comment: Please [ask] whats the error you are getting? and what happened to keyValue[0]

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 is the error i am receiving @Madhan

Comment: so i've made an 'Extract' object which contains the readFile method. In the main method, im making an object which reads a CSV. In the extract method, im attempting to read the CSV and store it into a hashmap but the hashmap needs 1 key and two values @CKing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the code as it should suit you. Try to understand what happens here. It seems that you're still struggling a little when it comes to Maps and how to use them properly.

```
public class Extract {



    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> readFile(String filename)   {

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> people = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> metaData = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            String line;

            while(in.hasNext()) {
                line = in.nextLine();
                String[] keyValue = line.split(",");

                // 1st put email address and age in the inner Map
                metaData = new HashMap<>();
                metaData.put("email", keyValue[1]);
                metaData.put("age", keyValue[2]);

                // 2nd put the inner Map into the outer Map, referenced by the person's name
                people.put(keyValue[0], metaData);
            }
            in.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return people;
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Extract e = new Extract();

        String peopleFile = ("relationships.csv");
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> person1 = e.readFile(peopleFile);

        // 1st:  get the inner Map of Bob
        // If you use the get()-method, you tell the outer Map to hand you the inner Map of Bob.
        HashMap<String, String> metaData = person1.get("Bob");

        // 2nd: get the metaData off the inner Map
        String email = metaData.get("email");
        Integer age = Integer.valueOf(metaData.get("age"));
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Are you sure that your values lay in keyValue[0], keyValue[2], keyValue[3]? Or did you mean keyValue[0], keyValue[1], keyValue[2]? Because ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException usually emanates from misconfigured indexes. This means either you overstep the rightmost or the bottommost index of an array.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. well the CSV file is laid out: 
bob, bob@example.com, 31 and so forth.
Also I've just attempted to run your code however there is an incompatible type error @DiabolicWords

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've corrected the code. I changed 'HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> person1 = e.readFile(peopleFile);' to 'HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> person1 = e.readFile(peopleFile);'. Also I corrected your indexes for the array. It should work now.

Comment: I tested it locally, just to be sure. The code above works now. I'd really appreciate your feedback. And please, don't forget to mark my solution.